# Change value in all unique keys in PHP serialize data

Tags: php

Here PHP serialize(d) data from database:

```
$data = 'a:5:{s:5:"width";i:700;s:6:"height";i:700;s:4:"file";s:22:"2020/11/fragrances.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:8:{s:21:"woocommerce_thumbnail";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-300x300.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:300;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:9:"uncropped";b:0;}s:29:"woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-100x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:18:"woocommerce_single";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-600x600.jpg";s:5:"width";i:600;s:6:"height";i:600;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:6:"medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-300x300.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:300;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:12:"shop_catalog";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-300x300.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:300;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:9:"uncropped";b:0;}s:11:"shop_single";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-600x600.jpg";s:5:"width";i:600;s:6:"height";i:600;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:14:"shop_thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-100x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:12:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";s:1:"0";s:8:"keywords";a:0:{}}}';
```

I need to change all **"file"** value to **"new-fragrances.png"**

```
$uns_data = unserialize($data);
$uns_data['file'] = 'new-fragrances.png';

$data = serialize($uns_data);

var_dump($data);
```

Resut (It only changed the first key value):

```
'a:5:{s:5:"width";i:700;s:6:"height";i:700;s:4:"file";s:18:"new-fragrances.png";s:5:"sizes";a:8:{s:21:"woocommerce_thumbnail";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-300x300.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:300;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:9:"uncropped";b:0;}s:29:"woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-100x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:18:"woocommerce_single";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-600x600.jpg";s:5:"width";i:600;s:6:'... (length=1571)
```

How can I change all **value** of the key **file**?

Comment: You have to loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to go through every item of an array. In this case, I would use [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php). In the callback function of `array_walk_recursive` do whatever you like with the values of each item of your array. In this example, I replace `fragrances` with `new_fragrances`:

```
$data = 'a:5:{s:5:"width";i:700;s:6:"height";i:700;s:4:"file";s:22:"2020/11/fragrances.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:8:{s:21:"woocommerce_thumbnail";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-300x300.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:300;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:9:"uncropped";b:0;}s:29:"woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-100x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:18:"woocommerce_single";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-600x600.jpg";s:5:"width";i:600;s:6:"height";i:600;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:6:"medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-300x300.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:300;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:12:"shop_catalog";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-300x300.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:300;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:9:"uncropped";b:0;}s:11:"shop_single";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-600x600.jpg";s:5:"width";i:600;s:6:"height";i:600;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:14:"shop_thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:22:"fragrances-100x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:12:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";s:1:"0";s:8:"keywords";a:0:{}}}';

$uns_data = unserialize($data);

array_walk_recursive($uns_data, function (&$value, $key){
    $value = str_replace('fragrances', 'new-fragrances', $value);
});

$data = serialize($uns_data);

var_dump($data);
```

Notice that `$value` is [passed by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), using `&$value`, so the original value can be modified.

Comment: It won't replace extension jpg to png and fragrances-300x300.jpg and fragrances-100x100.jpg to new-fragrances.png

Comment: You can do whatever you want in your callback function. If you want to rename everything containing `fragrances` to `new-fragrances.png` I would use something like: 
`$value = strpos($value, 'fragrances') === false ? $value : 'new-fragrances.png';`, here's a working example: https://3v4l.org/BArdn

Comment: Thanks a lot. However I did like `if ($key == 'file') $value = 'new-fragrance.png';` So I can replace the value by the key no matter what was the value. `array_walk_recursive` seems faster than I was testing with creating a function for finding and replacing with `foreach`.